# "Unknown type name" despite included framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, restkit, core-foundation

I'm trying (failing) to setup RestKit, which requires one Xcode project to be referenced inside of another. The RestKit framework file creates an NSRegularExpression and appropriately does a `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`. When I build, Xcode spits out "Unknown type name 'NSRegularExpression'".

I'm thinking there might be a circular reference to Core Foundation because I include it in my project and RestKit includes it in theirs? (Remember, the RestKit project is referenced inside of mine, as per their install instructions.)

**Also worth noting:** In my project build settings, I have the Header and Library search paths set to inside the `RestKit/Build` path, again, as per their instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was making the build settings on the project instead of the target. Making sure I was changing paths and libraries on the target instead of the project alleviated all my woes!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are building your project for iOS. If you included the RestKit.framework in your project, remove it. The .framework is meant to be used in Mac OS projects, add 'libRestKit.a' instead.

Comment: Thanks, mja. I'm only using the libRestKit.a and it still shows up red, while we're at it. In fact, I can't even find the file in either project.

Comment: Well, the fact it shows up red is not a problem at all. Did you included -ObjC -all_load in linker flags? The class NSRegularExpression is available only on Mac as far as i know... Do you use git/master or version downloaded from the website?

Comment: Gotcha. Good eye. I added the Mac framework and then removed it. Wonder if it left some residue? ... I did include those two linker flags in my project and I used the git submodule.

Comment: What's the difference between the git and the download versions?

Comment: I don't think there's any residue that can be left. Just be sure the "RestKit.framework" is removed from your Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries. The downloadable version was using an older project structure and build process. Since you have "RestKit.framework" available in your project it implies you are on git/master.